# libcurl crashes occasionally at curl_easy_perform

Tags: c++, ios, curl, libcurl

We use the following code to send messages to a server.  Assuming the URL is good, is there anything wrong with the following code?

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

**Code**

```
CURL *session = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_URL, requestData->url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, kConfigServerReadTimeout);
curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, kConfigServerConnectionTimeout);
curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, requestData->params.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, requestData->params.size());

CURLcode curl_code = curl_easy_perform(session);
```

**Crash Log:**

libsystem_platform.dylib 0x3a6cd058 _platform_strcmp + 0

libsystem_info.dylib 0x3a64ac81 _mdns_query_callback + 162

libsystem_dnssd.dylib 0x3a63b9d9 handle_query_response + 166

libsystem_dnssd.dylib 0x3a63a73f DNSServiceProcessResult + 580

libsystem_info.dylib 0x3a64a4c3 _mdns_search + 828

libsystem_info.dylib 0x3a649e75 mdns_addrinfo + 286

libsystem_info.dylib 0x3a64b9df search_addrinfo + 112

libsystem_info.dylib 0x3a643787 si_addrinfo + 1052

libsystem_info.dylib 0x3a6432fb getaddrinfo + 100

Macau 0x003a6b9f Curl_getaddrinfo_ex + 20

Macau 0x003af70f Curl_ipv4_resolve_r + 132

Macau 0x003af66d Curl_getaddrinfo + 18

Macau 0x003af25f Curl_resolv + 244

Macau 0x003af397 Curl_resolv_timeout + 220

Macau 0x003c77bb Curl_connect + 6036

Macau 0x003c39d9 Curl_do_perform + 170

Macau 0x003c38ff Curl_perform + 60

Macau 0x003a8c67 curl_easy_perform + 12

Comment: From the log it looks like the crash occurs while resolving the URL.  Any change that `requestData->url` has been destroyed before the `curl_easy_perform` has completed?  I suspect curl is not making a copy of the string.  It does not look like it from the code you've posted, but maybe what you've posted is not your actual code.

Comment: I was curious so I checked to see if curl copies strings. It DOES appear to do so, but not before version 7.17.0. Source [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html).